# Adding dynamic elements to Symfony form on PRE_SUBMIT

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I am trying to use Symfony Form Component with Silex framework at the moment. I added some fields in `buildForm` method of my form type class. Also user can click on a button and add unlimited `textarea` element using javascript on the frontend. Now on `PRE_SUBMIT` event, I do the following to add these fields to the form

```
        $data = $event->getData();
    $form = $event->getForm();
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if (stristr($key, '_tb_') !== false) {
            $id = str_ireplace('_tb_', '', $key);
            $form->add('_tb_' . $id, 'hidden');
            $form->add('_title_' . $id, 'text', [
                'required'    => false,
                'label'       => 'Title',
                'constraints' => [
                    new Length(['min' => 6]),
                ]
            ]);
            $form->add('_img_url_' . $id, 'text', [
                'required'    => false,
                'label'       => 'Image Url',
                'constraints' => [
                    new Url(),
                ]
            ]);
            $form->add('_img_alt_' . $id, 'text', [
                'required'    => false,
                'label'       => 'Image Alt',
                'constraints' => []
            ]);
            $form->add('_content_' . $id, 'textarea', [
                'required'    => true,
                'attr'        => [
                    'data-role' => '_richeditor'
                ],
                'constraints' => [
                    new Length(['min' => 100]),
                ]
            ]);
        }
    }
```

I can see these fields are added to the form and populated once the form is submitted for the first time but for some reason all the constraints are ignored only for these new added fields. Is there a way to force `Form` to honour the constraints for the newly added elements?

Comment: I've been unable to reproduce this issue from your example -- the constraints used on the dynamic fields are honored in my tests. Can you include the output of `$data` in your question? Unless you have the mistaken assumption that the `'required'=>true` attribute for your _content_ field implies a NotBlank() constraint?

Comment: `$data` would be something like `['_tb_1'=>'','_title_1'=>'','_img_url_1'=>'','_img_alt_1'=>'','_content_1'=>'']`. So I am expecting to get an error on `_content_1` as it cannot be empty. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form component and validation can be tricky. A easy misconception is that the form type option "required" will *imply a NotBlank validation constraint*. This is not the case, [the docs explain that option](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/textarea.html#required) to be "superficial and independent from validation" only concerned with form element rendering (HTML5 required attr, label, etc).

To make things trickier, that you are specifying a minimum length constraint, one might assume that no (or zero) length would be considered invalid. This is also not the case. The length validator is only concerned with [non-null / non-empty values](https://github.com/symfony/Validator/blob/v2.6.4/Constraints/LengthValidator.php#L32). :-/

So! Modifying the text area field to include NotBlank() should do the trick:

```
$form->add('_content_' . $id, 'textarea', [
    'required'    => true,
    'attr'        => [
        'data-role' => '_richeditor'
    ],
    'constraints' => [
        new NotBlank(),
        new Length(['min' => 100]),
    ]
]);
```

Comment: That was exactly the problem! This is the first time I am using this component and guess I still have loads to read. Thank you very much.